# Regex: ignore if url contains one of two words

Tags: regex

I am tracking clicks of some URLS and need to only track ones that do not contain the word "amazon" or "ebay"

eg I would like to track this

```
http://www.website.co.uk/out?prov=tesco*
http://www.website.co.uk/out?prov=asda*
http://www.website.co.uk/out?prov=youtube*
```

but not this

```
http://www.website.co.uk/out?prov=amazon*
```

or

```
http://www.website.co.uk/out?prov=ebay*
```

How would I approach the regex?

The star at the end of the URL is because each url has different parameters

Comment: you don't need regex for this. just allow those links that do not contain the specified substring in them

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex to match the url's except the one which contains  amazon or ebay,

```
http:\/\/www(?!.*amazon|.*ebay).*
```

OR

```
http:\/\/www(?!(?:.*amazon|.*ebay)).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vV4wU3)

Answer (score 1):

**Negative Lookahead**

Just add a negative lookahead at the head of your regex:

```
(?!.*(?:amazon|ebay))
```

This asserts: At this position in the string, what follows is not some characters, then `amazon` or `ebay`.

Use whatever syntax your language or engine requires to make that case-insensitive, for instance:

```
(?i)(?!.*(?:amazon|ebay))
```

**One Regex to Track them All**

One regex that tracks your three kinds of patterns could be:

```
(?i)^(?!.*(?:amazon|ebay))http://website\.co\.uk/out\?prov=(?:tesco|asda|youtube)\S*$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qF4eE5).

Of the final regex depends on the implementation context.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Hadn't noticed `ebay`, added that to the regex and demo. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't sat what language you're using, I'll assume Perl for the purposes of the answer. Here you would want to use something like:

```
if ($url !~ /prov=amazon/i and
     $url !~ /prov=ebay/i) {
    do_stuff();
}
```